# Which parts of HippoCms need Sencha ExtJs to work?

Tags: extjs, hippocms

I found this on the hippo cms licence page.

> All included libraries are distributed either under the Apache
>   Software License 2.0 or a compatible license, **with the exception of
>   the Sencha ExtJS library. Sencha ExtJS is distributed under GPL v3,
>   with an Open Source License Exception for Applications. If you
>   customise or redistribute Hippo Community Edition code that uses ExtJS
>   components, then you must comply to their open source licenses - or
>   buy an appropriate developer license from Sencha.**

As I want to distribute my product I would like to exclude everything that use Sencha ExtJS to keep the product in Apache 2.0 licence.
So my question is, which parts of HippoCMS need Sencha ExtJS to work ?
Because, for example if we can't create date without ExtJS, it's really bad because I (and the client) would like to use it, so that's why I am asking you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this discussion on our Community forum . 
[https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/hippo-community&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=false&parenturl=http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/about/cms-forums.html#!searchin/hippo-community/Sencha$20ExtJs$20/hippo-community/DWbI32Mw5Rk/dXvqZa-dgdQJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/hippo-community&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=false&parenturl=http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/about/cms-forums.html#!searchin/hippo-community/sencha/hippo-community/DWbI32Mw5Rk/dXvqZa-dgdQJ)